# What should I return from Importer when writing TF Provider?

Tags: go, terraform

Context: I'm developing a TF provider.

Let's say I'm implementing a complex import:

```
func fooResource() *schema.Resource {
    return &schema.Resource{
...
        Importer: &schema.ResourceImporter{
            StateContext: fooImport,
        },

...

func fooImport(ctx context.Context, d *schema.ResourceData, meta interface{}) ([]*schema.ResourceData, error) {
    ...
    return []*schema.ResourceData{d}, nil
}
```

So if the import was successful I should return `[]*schema.ResourceData{d}, nil`. What if my import failed, shall I return `nil` or `[]*schema.ResourceData{d}` as the first argument? Obviously, the second argument is going to be `err`.

Note: I found this [tutorial](https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/import) from HashiCorp but it doesn't say anything about it (they're using `ImportStatePassthrough`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for a complex resource import generally follows the structure below:

```
Importer: &schema.ResourceImporter{
  State: func(d *schema.ResourceData, meta interface{}) (result []*schema.ResourceData, err error) {
    ...
    if err {
      return nil, fmt.Errorf("my error message about the ID (%q)", d.Id())
    }

    d.Set("<resource_type>", d.Id())

    return []*schema.ResourceData{d}, nil
  },
},
```

so for your specific situation it would appear like:

```
Importer: &schema.ResourceImporter{
  StateContext: fooImport(ctx context.Context, d *schema.ResourceData, meta interface{}) (result []*schema.ResourceData, error) {
    ...
    if err {
      return nil, fmt.Errorf("my error message about the ID (%q)", d.Id())
    }

    d.Set("foo_resource", d.Id())

    return []*schema.ResourceData{d}, nil,
  },
}
```

So basically the first return type would be `nil`.

Side note: you mention `ImportStatePassthrough`, and in your situation with `context` the relevant helper may be `ImportStatePassthroughContext` instead.